# Getting value in rss feed using php

Tags: php, rss, domdocument

i want to get the value of a child in rss tag

the code i'm using :

```
$img = $item->getElementsByTagName('enclosure')->item(0)->firstChild->nodeValue;
```

and the value i want to get is the url of the image, this is the RSS :

```
<enclosure url="http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2015/05/19/10/28D9A90800000578-0-image-m-14_1432029086109.jpg" type="image/jpeg" length="13451"/>
```

what must i chang in my code to return the value of url? it's returning null now
thanks

Comment: it dosen't return anything now even null and the other values

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
<?php

$html = '<enclosure url="http://i.dailymail.co.uk/i/pix/2015/05/19/10/28D9A90800000578-0-image-m-14_1432029086109.jpg" type="image/jpeg" length="13451"/>';
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$img = $dom->getElementsByTagName('enclosure')->item(0);
echo $img->attributes->getNamedItem("url")->value;

?>
```

MORE : http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php#89313

Comment: `load()` used for file loading and `loadHTML()` used for loading string as HTML.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78172/discussion-between-makesh-and-sa-ha).